Reference request: Parabolic Schauder estimates for the heat equation with $f \in L^\infty$
Let us consider the heat equation
$$\partial_t u - \Delta u = f(x, t) \quad \text{in }Q_R $$
where $Q_R = B_R \times (-R^2,0].$ I would like to know the kind of regularity we should expect of $u$ if we assume $f \in L^\infty(Q_R)$.
I know that, for $f \in C^{\alpha}(Q_R)$, then by the parabolic Schauder estimate, $u \in C^{2 + \alpha, 1 + \alpha/2}(Q_R)$ and
$$\|u \|_{C^{2 + \alpha, 1 + \alpha/2}(Q_{R/2})} \le C\left(\frac{1}{R^{2 + \alpha}} |u|_{0;Q_R} + \frac{1}{R^{\alpha}} |f|_{0;Q_R} + [f]_{\alpha, \alpha/2;Q_R}\right).$$
Moreover, in the elliptic case $\Delta u = f$ in $B_1$, if we assume $f$ only bounded $f \in L^\infty$, then $u \in C^{1,1 - \varepsilon}$ inside $B_1$ for any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ and satisfies
$$\|u\|_{C^{1,1 - \varepsilon}(B_{1/2})} \le C_\varepsilon \left(\|f\|_{L^\infty(B_{1})} + \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1})}\right).$$
Therefore, I would be expecting the same type of behaviour for the parabolic case, meaning that $u \in C^{1 + \alpha, \alpha/2}(Q_{R/2})$ with the appropriate estimate. However, I have been looking for a reference proving such result, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

The estimates
$$\|u\|_{C^{1,1 - \varepsilon}(B_{1/2})} \le C_\varepsilon \left(\|f\|_{L^\infty(B_{1})} + \|u\|_{L^\infty(B_{1})}\right)$$
is not a Schauder estimate. In fact, it comes form an interior
$L^p$ estimates (Calderon-Zygmund estimates) for
$-\Delta u=f$ and the Sobolev embedding. That is,
$$ \|u\|_{W^{2,p}(B_1)} \leq C \|u\|_{L^p(B_2)} +C\|f\|_{L^p(B_2)} \leq C \|u\|_{L^{\infty}(B_2)} +C\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_2)}.$$
And  $$\|u\|_{C^{1,1-\epsilon}(B_1)}\leq C \|u\|_{W^{2,\frac{n}{\epsilon}}(B_1)}.$$
As for the heat equation, the results is similar to the above.

Thank you for your answer but I would like to find a reference proving this similar result for the heat equation. I couldn't find it anywhere.

For instance, consider Theorem 9.2.1 in "Elliptic and Parabolic Equations" by Zhuoqun Wu, Jingxue Yin, and Chunpeng Wang (DOI: 10.1142/6238). To establish an interior estimate, one can multiply $u$ by a cutoff function $\varphi$ and apply Theorem 9.2.1 to the product $u\varphi$. The dependence on
$R$ follows from a standard scaling argument.

Sorry I don't quite see how to do what you suggest. Would you mind to elaborate a bit more?
